# How to use nested Attribute to set value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

How am I able to set the value of a variable in XSLT?

I currently have an xml like so:

```
<field name="Average Bitrate" timecode="01:35:14:300" value="60.01" />
<field name="Display Aspect Ratio" value="16:9" />
<field name="GOP Structure">
```

I would like to create a variable called aspectratio. This variable needs to have the conditions under the node field with the attribute Display Aspect Ratio. In this case the value would then be 16:9

Here is an example of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="$cfg//taskReport/streamnode/info/"/>
<xsl:variable name="AspectRatio" select="$root/Field[name = 'Display Aspect Ratio']">
    <xsl:value-of select="$AspectRatio/@value"/>
</xsl:variable>
```

What do I need to change in order to get my desired result?

Comment: It's virtually impossible to answer your question because of lack of context. We don't know the true path to the `field` in question, and we don't know where you are in your XSLT stylesheet. And you are showing us undefined variables e.g. `$cfg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the following input:

**XML**

```
<root>
    <field name="Average Bitrate" timecode="01:35:14:300" value="60.01" />
    <field name="Display Aspect Ratio" value="16:9" />
    <field name="GOP Structure"/>
</root>
```

the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="AspectRatio" select="/root/field[@name='Display Aspect Ratio']/@value" />
    <test>
        <xsl:value-of select="$AspectRatio"/>
    </test>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test>16:9</test>
```

---

Note that XML is case-sensitive; `Field` does not select `field`.